# JMeter Security Token not parsed

Tags: apache, jmeter, token, confluence

I'm busy with a performance test for Confluence created by JMeter. But I'm having a problem with a security token that is required for creating a page with a post function. This is the query I use, the atl_token is presented in the query:

```
spaceKey=BD&titleWritten=false&linkCreation=false&title=TEST1&wysiwygContent=TEST1kahdjkaskdjadhkajdlkajsdjaldkjsadlajksdjakldjlkacmnlknmclknmlsanmclanmlclanmldmaldlksadlasmdcalcmlamlamclmalkdjsakjdalksxlakmkslmlknmdlasmdlasdad&confirm=Save&parentPageString=Backend+Development+Home&moveHierarchy=true&atl_token=c52cba0fa075e0fde71e3a5546b95a049e9926a8
```

But when I use this query and paste into a webpage it says the following:

```
Your session has expired. You may need to re-submit the form or reload the page.
```

Is this a timeout or should I do something else in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to your test plan. They will in most cases keep track of SessionID (store and send it).

You could also read few articles online about how to use these components in practice to get better understanding of them...

Comment: I'm having a HTTP Header Manager with a line 'X- Atlassian- Token' - 'no-check' but still same error..

Comment: Yes. Implemenation: HC4CookieHandler, Cookie Policy: standard

Answer (score 0):

There are following measures you can take to get rid of this issue:

1. Add cookie manager to your script.
2. Check the response of the request before the Post request. Ideally if should have atl_token.
3. If you find the token in earlier request, add Regular Expression Extractor to that request and fetch the token.
4. Pass that token in actual query that you are calling to create page.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: Unfortunately no success. I have added a Regular Expression Extractor to get the token but still this error within Confluence when Jmeter creates a page: 

Your request could not be processed because a required security token was not present in the request. You may need to re-submit the form or reload the page.